# How to add a scrollbar to window made with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

## A simple quiz game

I got this code and I need scrollbars, I tried to search how to add it on stackoverflow (ScrolledWindow with tix...) but I still can't get something that works properly. Could someone help me?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title("Quiz")
root.geometry("400x300")


class Window:

    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.text = [question, answer]
        self.createLabel()
        # self.createText()
        self.createEntry()
        self.createButton()

    def retrieve_input(self):
        # inputValue = self.textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        # print(inputValue)
        if self.mystring.get() == self.text[1]:
            print("Esatto. è " + self.text[1])
            self.left['text'] = "Esatto"

    def createLabel(self):
        self.labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text="Domanda:")
        self.labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
        self.left = Label(self.labelframe, text=self.text[0])
        self.left.pack()

    def createText(self):
        self.textBox = Text(height=1)
        self.textBox.pack()

    def createEntry(self):
        self.mystring = StringVar()
        self.myentry = Entry(root, textvariable=self.mystring).pack()

    def createButton(self):
        self.but = Button(text="Click", command=self.retrieve_input)
        self.but.pack()


for i in range(10):
    one = randint(1, 10)
    two = randint(1, 10)
    Window("Quanto fa " + str(one) + "+" + str(two) + "?", str(one + two))

root.mainloop()
```

> output

[image]

Comment: there are examples how to scroll `Frame` using `Canvas` like this [`ScrolledFrame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas/scrolledframe.py) and [examples of use](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `ScrolledFrame` it can look like this

[image]

- I renamed `Window` into `Question` because it makes more sense
- I use `self.question` and `self.answer` instead of  `self.text = [question, answer]` to make it more readable.
- I put classes and functions before `root = tk.Tk()` to make it more readable.
- I use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *`  to make it more readable.

`Question` gets inner frame from `ScrolledFrame` and use as parent for `LabelFrame`. Other widgets use `labelframe` as parent.

BTW: you had `entry = Entry(..).pack()` which assign `None` to `entry` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`. I put `pack()` in next line and now I can get text directly from `Entry` (without `StringVar`)

Code

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

# --- classes ---

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas, bg='red')
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.frame_width)

    def frame_width(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        canvas_width = event.width
        self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width = canvas_width)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

class Question:

    def __init__(self, parent, question, answer):
        self.parent = parent
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.create_widgets()

    def get_input(self):
        value = self.entry.get()
        print('value:', value)
        if value == self.answer:
            print("Esatto. è " + self.answer)
            self.label['text'] = "Esatto"

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Domanda:")
        self.labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.labelframe, text=self.question)
        self.label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.labelframe)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.labelframe, text="Click", command=self.get_input)
        self.button.pack()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Quiz")
root.geometry("400x300")

window = ScrolledFrame(root)
window.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

for i in range(10):
    one = randint(1, 10)
    two = randint(1, 10)
    Question(window.inner, "Quanto fa {} + {} ?".format(one, two), str(one + two))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much furas, I was getting really confused trying to add the scrollbar to that window.