# how to display matplotlib charts in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i am trying to display 4 or more charts in tkinter windows but they are misplaced and i thinks i need a scroll bar also . this is the code :

```
root = tk.Tk()

    figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)

    ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(221)
    ax1.plot(df1['year'], df1['personal'], color='red')
    scatter1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root)
    scatter1.get_tk_widget().pack()
    ax1.legend([''])
    ax1.set_xlabel('valeur de personals')
    ax1.set_title('ev de personal ')

    figure2 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)
    ax2 = figure2.add_subplot(222)
    scatter2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure2, root)
    scatter2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    ax2.legend([''])
    ax2.set_xlabel('valeur BSA')
    ax2.set_title('Evolutiion des valeurs BSA depuis 1990 ')
    ax2.plot(df2['year'], df2['value'], color='red')

    figure3 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)
    ax3 = figure3.add_subplot(223)
    #the same code for the reste 


    root.mainloop()
```

but this is the result :
[image: charts misplaced graph]

Comment: if you put plots in separated `FigureCanvasTkAgg` then you don't need `subplot(`221`)`  (etc.) because it creates place for 4 plots in every `FigureCanvasTkAgg` but you use only one place in every `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. If you want to use `subplot(`221`)`  then you need only one `FigureCanvasTkAgg` for this.

Comment: @furas but  FigureCanvasTkAgg has no  attribute 'plot' to   plot(df1['year'], df1['personal'], color='red')

Comment: use normal `plot` but don't create new `figure` and new `FigureCanvasTkAgg` for every new plot.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems

**First:**

You create 4 canvas `FigureCanvasTkAgg` and on every canvas you use `add_subplot(222)` to create places for 4 plots (2x2) but you use only one place in every canvas. You could use only one canvas for this.

**Second:**

You need `pack(fill="both", expand=True)` to resize plots and use all space in window.

You also use `pack(side=tk.RIGHT)` which can make problem with layout

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2001, 2002, 2003],
    'value': [1, 3, 2],
    'personal': [9, 1, 5],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2001, 2002, 2003],
    'value': [1, 3, 2],
    'personal': [9, 1, 5],
})

# --- 

root = tk.Tk()

figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)

scatter = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)
scatter.get_tk_widget().pack() #fill='both', expand=True)

# --- 

ax1 = figure.add_subplot(221)
ax1.plot(df1['year'], df1['personal'], color='red')

ax1.legend([''])
ax1.set_xlabel('valeur de personals')
ax1.set_title('ev de personal ')

# --- 

ax2 = figure.add_subplot(222)
ax2.plot(df2['year'], df2['value'], color='red')

ax2.legend([''])
ax2.set_xlabel('valeur BSA')
ax2.set_title('Evolutiion des valeurs BSA depuis 1990 ')

# --- 

ax3 = figure.add_subplot(223)
ax3.plot(df1['year'], df1['personal'], color='red')

ax3.legend([''])
ax3.set_xlabel('valeur de personals')
ax3.set_title('ev de personal ')

# --- 

ax4 = figure.add_subplot(224)
ax4.plot(df2['year'], df2['value'], color='red')

ax4.legend([''])
ax4.set_xlabel('valeur BSA')
ax4.set_title('Evolutiion des valeurs BSA depuis 1990 ')

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

The same with 4 canvas - and every canvas keep only one plot using `add_plot('111')` - but this time I use `grid()` instead of `pack()` to organize it.

It needs `columnconfigure`, `rowconfigure` to resize cells and use all space in window. And `grid( ..., sticky='news')` to resize canvas to cell's size.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2001, 2002, 2003],
    'value': [1, 3, 2],
    'personal': [9, 1, 5],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2001, 2002, 2003],
    'value': [1, 3, 2],
    'personal': [9, 1, 5],
})

# --- 

root = tk.Tk()

# resize grid
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

# --- 

figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)

scatter1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root)
scatter1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
#scatter1.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(df1['year'], df1['personal'], color='red')

ax1.legend([''])
ax1.set_xlabel('valeur de personals')
ax1.set_title('ev de personal ')

# --- 

figure2 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)

scatter2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure2, root)
scatter2.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')
#scatter2.get_tk_widget().pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=True)

ax2 = figure2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(df2['year'], df2['value'], color='red')

ax2.legend([''])
ax2.set_xlabel('valeur BSA')
ax2.set_title('Evolutiion des valeurs BSA depuis 1990 ')

# --- 

figure3 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)

scatter3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure3, root)
scatter3.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
#scatter3.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

ax3 = figure3.add_subplot(111)
ax3.plot(df1['year'], df1['personal'], color='red')

ax3.legend([''])
ax3.set_xlabel('valeur de personals')
ax3.set_title('ev de personal ')

# --- 

figure4 = plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2), dpi=100)

scatter4 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure4, root)
scatter4.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')
#scatter4.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

ax4 = figure4.add_subplot(111)
ax4.plot(df2['year'], df2['value'], color='red')

ax4.legend([''])
ax4.set_xlabel('valeur BSA')
ax4.set_title('Evolutiion des valeurs BSA depuis 1990 ')

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

Now plots has smaller margins.

[image]

Comment: I added example which uses 4 canvas but this time I use `grid()` instead of `pack()` to put canvas in 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: i want to add a scroll bar but all tutorial that i found are using frame

Comment: `tkinter` can use scroller with widgets `Text`, `LIstbox` or `Canvas` and only method to scroll other elements is to put widgets on `Canvas` and scroll this `Canvas`. You can put `Frame` on `Canvas` with scrollers (to build "Scrolled Frame") and put plots in this `Frame` like in [How to add a scrollbar to window made with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727404/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-window-made-with-tkinter).

Comment: I keep code for `ScrolledFrame` on Guthub in [python-examples -> Scrolled Frame and Canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas) but someone created also module [tkScrolledFrame](https://pypi.org/project/tkScrolledFrame/)